# Install JVM for Oracle 11g XE

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, java

I am trying to configure `JavaMail` in my `Oracle 11g XE(11.2.0.2.0)` database, which requires `loadjava` utility. But after some research I came to know that XE version of Oracle doesn't provide Java/JVM as some restriction in Free version of database.

I can not install Licence Version of Database, but want to install/configure Java service in my XE database if possible.

I was following this post [How To Install Oracle JVM](http://abcdba.com/abcdbaserverinstallguideshowtoinstalloraclejvm), but not able to locate `/javavm/install/initjvm.sql` in my oracle directory.

if anyone knows some solution, help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

No way how to do that. XE version does not support Java Stored Procedures.
You have to upgrade at least to "Standard Edition One" or "Oracle Personal Edition".

[See edition comparsion.](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/enterprise-edition/comparisons/index.html)

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as correct so that others with the same problem can find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not supported.

If you want to send e-mails (JavaMail?) from the database, you do not need Java in the database for that, just use the [UTL_MAIL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_mail.htm#ARPLS384) package, available in XE as well.

Comment: thanks for your response,
I was actually using UTL_MAIL only, but clients were getting some emails after 8 minuts, and sometimes after half day, even I am pushing mail queue each time. also we want to send Authenticated Mail, so I am trying to configure JavaMail (FYI, I am using `Oracle APEX`)

Comment: OT: if you want investigate problems with email you should set SMTP_SERVER to localhost on your DB server. Then Oracle will imediatelly handover email to Sendmail/Postfix and then it's MTAs problem. In the /var/log/maillog you will find a reason why email delivery was postponed. And Unix admins usualy know what to do in these cases.